# How to compare two huge text files (more than 50gb each)?

Tags: bash, unix, text-files, diff, file-comparison

I have 2 huge text files and want to find the difference between them?
What is the fast command/ utility/ or script to do this job?

I try using `unix diff` but, it failed for huge files. It show me `"Permission Denied"`

Also, I try `unix bdiff` (as I read that is good for huge files) but, I did not complete test it because it show me `"bdiff: command not found"`

Also, I try `windows FC` (file compare) but, I did not know how to show the output in a new text file. The result output in the cmd and I can't figure it all.

Any suggestion will help me a lot.
Please help me in this matter.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `diff` is the way to go here, but you will have to make sure you have permission to access the files. Where are the files saved and what are the permissions on the files?

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36516603/45375).

Comment: @Munir I put all test text files in the same folder and have full access to this folder. For small size files, it works but, for the huge one, it gives me that error.

Comment: Are you sure the large files have the same permission as the small ones?

Comment: The number of lines are the same in both files?

Comment: @Cyrus no not the same. I try diff again, it does not show permission denied but, my computer hang for a long time then it shows: memory exahusted

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [rdiff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033866/3776858).

Comment: @Cyrus what is rdiff? I read the post it sounds good but, is it cygwin utility? or what? from where can I download it? how to write it inside my php code?

Comment: @Cyrus please help me. I want to test rdiff. I download something called: cwRsync_5.4.1_x86_Free Is it related to rdiff?

Comment: [The rdiff utility uses the rsync algorithm to generate delta files with the difference from file A to file B (like the utility diff, but in a different delta format).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#rdiff) With Ubuntu you can install rdiff this way: `sudo apt-get install rdiff`. I don't know whether  there is a port for cygwin or php.

Comment: @Cyrus I hope I am not bothering you. I am using Windows and I install cygwin cmd. I try to type: sudo apt-get install rdiff in cygwin but, I got: bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: I suggest to ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 8):

You can try `diff`  with the `--speed-large-files` option :

```
diff --speed-large-files file1 file2
```

`cmp` is another alternative (compare files byte by byte) :

```
cmp file1 file2
```

Comment: @Eugene when I try it, the system hang!

Comment: cmp it is not what I want. I want to see the whole mismatches.

Comment: With files about 20 GB I get `diff: stack overflow` at least on WSL.

Comment: From the Mac diff man page:  
>       --speed-large-files. 
>            stub option for compatibility with GNU diff. 
  
So this option may not actually do anything for some versions of diff..

Answer (score 1):

If `fc` works for you, you can send the output of `fc` to text file with:

```
fc file1 file2 >output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I try it now and I see the result in the new file but, it seems that it does not type the all mismatches! why? it works amazing for the huge file but, why not type all the mismatches? what I want exactly is like what diff do.

Comment: Also, why there is: Resync Failed.  Files are too different.?

Comment: So it just try to find the (similarity) and stop comparing when there is a lot of mismatches! I do not want that. I want a tool that types all the differences exactly as diff utility.